# Proof by induction: $3^n|a_n\ $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction, divisibility, integers

$$Problem$$

Given $ (a_n)_{n\in N}$ the sequence defined by:

$$a_1=15,\ a_2=18,\ a_{n+2}=6a_{n+1}-7a_n^4,\ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$

Prove by induction that $\forall n \in N$

a) $3^n|a_n$

b) $3^{n+1}\not| \ a_n $

> I don't know how to face this problem properly, here's what I did. Is it >ok? Is there something I'm missing or a proper way to solve it?

$$My \ solution$$
a)

> First I define $P(n)$ like this:
>   $$P(n): 3^n|a_n$$

Then I test the base cases
$$P(1): 3|15, \ true \\ P(2):3^2|18, \ true$$

> So I assume that
>   $P(n)$ (already defined), and 
>   $$P(n+1):3^{n+1}|a_{n+1}$$
>   are true and try to assure that they imply $$P(n+2):3^{n+2}|a_{n+2}$$
>   So now, I try to prove by induction that the last statement is true, so I write it in other way (with the definition of $a_{n+2}$) in order to operate, like this:
>   $$6a_{n+1}-7a_n^4=3^{n+2}q\ \ ,q\in \mathbb{Z}$$

then 
$$\frac{6a_{n+1}}{3^{n+2}}-\frac{7a_n^4}{3^{n+2}}=q$$

and by hypothesis I know that $\frac{a_{k+1}}{3^{k+1}}\ and \frac{a_k}{3^k}$ are integers, I'll call them $s$ and $t$ respectively:

$$\frac{6s}{3}-\frac{7a_n^3t}{3^2}=q\ (with\ s,t,q \in \mathbb{Z})$$
$$2s-7\dfrac{a_n}{3}\dfrac{a_n}{3}a_nt=q$$
and again we know that if $3^n | a_n$ then $3| a_n$ because $3|3^n$, so $\frac{a_n}{3}\in \mathbb{Z}$.

> Finally defining $r$ as $\frac{a_n}{3}$ I get the equation
>   $$q=2s-7r^2a_nt$$ which I'm sure has solutions $\in \mathbb{Z}$ since all terms are integers.
>
> Is it enough to prove that $P(n+2)$ is true?

b)

> I don't know how to start this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're given $a_1$ and $a_2$ without the formula, so your base case has to be $a_3$.

$$a_3=6(18)-7(15)^4=-354267=3^3(-13121)$$
So true for $a_3$.

Now, we assume $3^k|a_k$ and $3^{k+1}|a_{k+1}$. To this end, let $$a_k=\lambda \cdot 3^k; 3\not|\lambda$$
$$a_{k+1}=\mu\cdot 3^{k+1}; 3\not|\mu$$

Can you see that:

$$a_{k+2}=2\mu\cdot 3^{k+2} -7\lambda\cdot 3^{4k}$$
$$a_{k+2}=3^{k+2}\bigg[2\mu-7\lambda\cdot 3^{3k-2}\bigg]$$

Since $3k-2>0$ across the range, this is sufficient for both parts of the question.

Comment: Assume as your inductive hypothesis that $3 \not \vert \mu \text{ and } 3 \not \vert \lambda$ and this proof is one step away from proving part (b) as well.

Comment: Yes very true. I'll add that.

Comment: Your induction works for $k\ge 1$, so you don’t have to calculate $a_3$ explicitly, just use $a_2$ as your base case.  You should still state that $a_1$ and $a_2$ are verified as you make use of them in your induction.